# How to add tabpages dynamically to the beginning of the tabcontrol

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a tab control that I can programmatically add and remove tabs from. It works fine but whenever I add a tab this tab is added end of the tab list. How can I add tabs beginning of the tabList dynamically.

This is the code I use to add tabs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Kare");

    }
```

Thanks from now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it:

you should change your code to that:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0,"Başlık");
```

let me explain what it means insert is like add but instead of adding tabs to the end of the list it allows the user to choose where the tab will be added. In my case it will be  the beginning of the tab list.
 0 means beginning of the list or the first tab and "Başlık" stands for the name of my tab.